# Angular, erro no AppComponent e no AppModule, não está importando

Tags: angular, navegador-de-internet, app, angular-material, angular-module

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html' 
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'frontend';
}
```

**app.modules.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

 @NgModule({
     declarations: [
         AppComponent,
     ],
     imports: [
         BrowserModule,
         AppRoutingModule
     ],
     providers: [],
     bootstrap: [AppRoutingModule]

 })

export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Poderia postar os erros exibidos no angular-cli? Juntamente com algum erro (se houve) do console do browser? Qual versão do angular utilizado?

Comment: Estou usando o angular 9 estou iniciando, estou bem perdida...


Failed to compile.

src/app/app.module.ts:5:30 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './app.component' or its corresponding type declarations.

5 import { AppComponent } from './app.component';



Esse é o erro, eu removi o AppComponent da importação, mas ainda continua dando erro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para resolver o problema, no arquivo `app.component.ts` é necessário remover a linha:

```
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
```

Dessa forma tudo deve voltar a funcionar.

Comment: Eu removi mais ele ainda está dando erro :/

Comment: Coloquei as imagens

Comment: Mudar a extensão do arquivo `app.component`, a extensão deve ser `.ts`, atualmente está `.js`